# How is webform node type is defined in webform module?

Tags: nodes, webforms

Reading the webform module code I could not figure out how webform content type is defined. I only found this piece of code:

```
function webform_node_type($op, $info) {
  $webform_types = webform_variable_get('webform_node_types');
  $affected_type = isset($info->old_type) ? $info->old_type : $info->type;
  $key = array_search($affected_type, $webform_types);
  if ($key !== FALSE) {
    if ($op == 'update') {
      $webform_types[$key] = $info->type;
    }
    if ($op == 'delete') {
      unset($webform_types[$key]);
    }
    variable_set('webform_node_types', $webform_types);
  }
}
```

In variable table of drupal database I found the following webform_node_types variable: a:1:{i:0;s:7:"webform";}. When applying variable_get to this variable I recieve an array of 1 element with value - 'webform'. 
Please help me understand how webform node type actually is defined and how it works?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial webform content type is created during install as an entity of type node. The code can be found in the [webform_install()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.install/function/webform_install/7) function:

```
$webform_type = array(
  'type' => 'webform',
  'name' => st('Webform'),
  'base' => 'node_content',
  'description' => st('Create a new form or questionnaire accessible to users. Submission results and statistics are recorded and accessible to privileged users.'),
  'custom' => TRUE,
  'modified' => TRUE,
  'locked' => FALSE,
);
$webform_type = node_type_set_defaults($webform_type);
node_type_save($webform_type);
if (variable_get('webform_install_add_body_field', FALSE)) {
  node_add_body_field($webform_type);
}
```

Additionally it might be worth noting, that you can turn any content type into a webform by checking the appropriate setting on the content types main configuration page. You can think of webform as an add-on extension to other content types. To find out which content types are "webform enabled" you should use the provided API functions. In webform-7.x-4.0-beta for example that would be `webform_node_types()`.