# Why does webform module uses $node->webform as a property?

Tags: nodes, webforms

Why does webform module uses $node->webform as a property instead of $node->type['webform'] or something like that?

Comment: I can't imagine what *[actual problems](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* can it cause. Could you elaborate why it bothers you and what problems it causes for you? If no, and it's only your curiosity, you should rather ask module maintainer using contact info on drupal.org or support request in issue queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because webform is not integrated to drupal entity concept

check entity form module that is integrated with drupal entity
https://drupal.org/project/entityform

Comment: Can you explain how then webform defines its node type?

Comment: @user2490392 See my answer here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102855/how-is-webform-node-type-is-defined-in-webform-module/102866#102866 to your own question.